# Interpreting effects in a meta analysis random intercepts regression model

Tags: regression, bayesian, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

I have a random intercepts model with two different clustering levels: studies and countries within which these studies were made.

So, my interest is to estimate a model to figure out the grand mean of the effect sizes from these studies. But also check for the effect of the countries.

[image]

The plot above shows 95% Credibility Interval of the grand mean as well as intercepts for countries. Since the CI is very wide, M = 1.41 [-1.75; 3.98], we can assume no meaningful effect here. But this is mostly due to the high variability across studies. The two posterior densities from the `country` level don't overlap. Does this mean that the `country` does have an effect? Or the fact that these two densities are within such a wide CI of the grand mean, that no meaningful things could be said further?